# System.QueryException: Aggregate query does not support queryMore()

Tags: trigger, aggregate

I am trying to deploy around 80 Components which include Apex Class,Trigger and Visualforce Pages. But it is failing due to below exception,

> MyTrigger: execution of BeforeInsert caused by: System.QueryException: Aggregate query does not support queryMore(), use LIMIT to restrict the results to a single batch Trigg...

All test classes are run as a part of deployement process hence few of the test classes are making this trigger fire causing error. As its a change set deployment error, could not get the complete error statement. Also my trigger includes below code.

```
if(trigger.isBefore & trigger.isInsert) {
        for(AggregateResult ar : [select ABC__c, Name, max(Revision__c) maxRev from XYZ__c 
                                    where ABC__c in :oppMap.keySet()
                                    group by ABC__c, Name order by ABC__c, Name]) {
            decimal maxRev = Integer.valueOf(ar.get('maxRev'));
            string oppAppKey = String.valueOf(ar.get('ABC__c')) + String.valueOf(ar.get('Name'));
            lrMap.put(oppAppKey, maxRev);
        }
    }
```

Let me know how to fix this. Should i try using limit or is there any other solution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I updated my code as below and it worked for me.

```
 Integer recordCount = [select count() from XYZ__c where ABC__c in :oppMap.keySet()];
            Integer sizeBlock = recordCount/2000 + (math.mod(recordCount,2000)!=0?1:0) ;
            Set<Id> setAppIds = new Set<Id>(); 

            //Iterate aggregate result with blocks of 2000 to avoid exception
            for(Integer i=0;i<sizeBlock;i++){            
                for(AggregateResult ar : [select id,ABC__c, Name, max(Revision__c) maxRev from XYZ__c
                                            where ABC__c in :oppMap.keySet() and id not in :setAppIds 
                                            group by id,ABC__c, Name order by ABC__c, Name limit 2000]) {
                    decimal maxRev = Integer.valueOf(ar.get('maxRev'));
                    string oppAppKey = String.valueOf(ar.get('ABC__c')) + String.valueOf(ar.get('Name'));
                    lrMap.put(oppAppKey, maxRev);
                    setAppIds.add(Id.valueOf(String.valueOf(ar.get('id'))));
                }
            }
```

courtesy :- @Peter Knolle

Comment: I'm glad this worked for you. Just to be safe, you might want to double check that the usage of `limit 2000` here isn't causing you to miss expected rows. I guess it will work since you are grouping by and subsequently excluding by  Application__c.Id.

Comment: @DanielBallinger Ya it does work with the help of grouping by & excluding id using set. Thanks 4 ua help.

Answer (score 2):

All my searches for that error message indicated it was occurring during batch Apex. Is it possible this trigger if firing during batch processing?

If so, a short term fix might be to exclude the query in batch context using [`System.isBatch()`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_system.htm#apex_System_System_isBatch).

---

In the Nonprofit Stater Pack the same error message was recorded as an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/npsp/issues/detail?id=218#c4). The corresponding [checkin/revision 483](https://code.google.com/p/npsp/source/browse/households/trunk/src/classes/OpportunityRollups.cls?spec=svn483&r=483) showed the SOQL query changing from:

```
for (sobject r : Database.query(soqlStatement)){
    // ...
}
```

To (edited to show just the important parts):

```
//generic object list for database query results
//resolves aggregrate querymore issue
list<sobject> objectList = database.query(soqlStatement);
        
for (sobject r : objectList ) {
    // ...
}
```

So you might try:

```
List<sObject> results = [select ABC__c, Name, max(Revision__c) maxRev from XYZ__c 
                                where ABC__c in :oppMap.keySet()
                                group by ABC__c, Name order by ABC__c, Name];
for(sObject ar : results ) {
        decimal maxRev = Integer.valueOf(ar.get('maxRev'));
        string oppAppKey = String.valueOf(ar.get('ABC__c')) + String.valueOf(ar.get('Name'));
        lrMap.put(oppAppKey, maxRev);
}
```

---

As per comment from [@peter-knolle](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/154/peter-knolle) to the official documentation:

> Note that queries including an aggregate function don't support `queryMore`. A runtime exception occurs if you use a query containing an aggregate function that returns more than 2000 rows in a `for` loop. Source: [SOQL For Loops Versus Standard SOQL Queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_loops_for_SOQL.htm?q=+SOQL+For+Loops+Versus)

So it is the combination of the SOQL for loop syntax and more than 2000 aggregate results that is causing the error.

Comment: hey @Daniel, i just tried to query in developer console query editor. It gave me the same error asking to put a limit. Does that mean the query is wrong. how am i supposed to overcome that.

Comment: How many XYZ__c records are there in production versus the environment you are deploying from?

Comment: Sandbox - 6994 records
Production - 7054 records

Comment: Strange part is that trigger code is getting covered by test class. It mean that code/query works. But it gives error while deployment.

Comment: Over the [2000 limit for Aggregate queries](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_loops_for_SOQL.htm): "Note that queries including an aggregate function don't support queryMore. A runtime exception occurs if you use a query containing an aggregate function that returns more than 2000 rows in a for loop."

Comment: @snehakem As Peter pointed out, it is the SOQL for loop syntax that is causing the error with more than 2000 records. I suspect this occurring in the developer console query editor as it to is trying to use the `queryMore` call. Try the direct list assignment instead.

Comment: Well, even with LIMIT 20 it is failing for me. I am trying to run a batch job. So I did a LIMIT 20 and a batch job size of 30 and I am still getting this error message.

Comment: @SanderdeJong Maybe ask a new question with the specifics of your problem.

Comment: Updated Doc link for @PeterKnolle's comment above, showing the 2000 record limit for Agg Queries: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_loops_for_SOQL.htm?q=%20SOQL%20For%20Loops%20Versus

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already using in your SOQL statement a GROUP BY and ORDER BY clause, an alternative approach is to add LIMIT and OFFSET:

```
Integer batchSize = 2000;
Integer nrOfRecordsProcessed = 0;

Integer rowsReturned = batchSize;
while (rowsReturned == batchSize) {
  rowsReturned = 0;
  for(AggregateResult ar : [select ABC__c, Name, max(Revision__c) maxRev from XYZ__c 
                            where ABC__c in :oppMap.keySet()
                            group by ABC__c, Name order by ABC__c, Name 
                            LIMIT :batchSize OFFSET :nrOfRecordsProcessed]) {
    decimal maxRev = Integer.valueOf(ar.get('maxRev'));
    string oppAppKey = String.valueOf(ar.get('ABC__c')) + String.valueOf(ar.get('Name'));
    lrMap.put(oppAppKey, maxRev);
    rowsReturned++;
  }
  nrOfRecordsProcessed = nrOfRecordsProcessed + rowsReturned;
}
```

This way you don't need to modify the query with a different grouping criteria and an additional condition. Also, you don't need the additional Set and neither the first SOQL to get the COUNT().

Answer (score 0):

Implementing Iterable interface instead of Query Locator in batch class.

```
global class AggregateResultIterator Implements Iterator<AggregateResult>{ 

AggregateResult [] results {get;set;} 
Integer index {get;set;} 

global AggregateResultIterator(){ 
String query = 'select Id, Max(ModifiedDate) from Campaign GROUP BY Id '; 
results = Database.query(query); 
} 

global boolean hasNext(){ 
return results !=null && !results.isEmpty() && index < results.size(); 
} 

global AggregateResult next(){ 
return results[index++]; 
} 
}
```