# EXCEEDED_ID_LIMIT: Aggregate query does not support queryMore(), use LIMIT to restrict the results to a single batch error is thrown REST API

Tags: rest-api, aggregate

We are making REST API call to execute and get SOQL query results from a Salesforce org through batch class which is failing with the error message EXCEEDED_ID_LIMIT: Aggregate query does not support queryMore(), use LIMIT to restrict the results to a single batch.

Eg : select DAY_ONLY(CreatedDate) CreatedDate, DAY_ONLY(LastModifiedDate) LastModifiedDate, DAY_ONLY(Request_Date__c) RequestDate, Status__c, Country_ISO_Code_ims__c, COUNT(Id) totalCount from Validation_Request__c group by DAY_ONLY(CreatedDate), DAY_ONLY(LastModifiedDate), DAY_ONLY(Request_Date__c), Status_ims__c, Country_ISO_Code__c

Issue persists even after trying below

- We have tried the resolution given in below Salesforce article with data and hour filters.
  https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000386516&type=1
- We thought of using OFFSET but offsets are not intended to be used as a replacement for using queryMore() and gives NUMBER_OUTSIDE_VALID_RANGE error when requesting an offset greater than 2,000 results.
  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_offset.htm
- We don't get nextRecordsUrl in response when we get Aggregate query does not support queryMore() exception.

Please let us know the workarounds to resolve the issue.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [take the tour](/tour). Including a [Minimal, Complete and Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [System.QueryException: Aggregate query does not support queryMore()](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/33100/system-queryexception-aggregate-query-does-not-support-querymore) [Aggregate query does not support queryMore](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/55541/aggregate-query-does-not-support-querymore)

Comment: No this doesn't answer my question as in the first link given grouping is done by Id field also which will return all the records in the object as is, instead of grouping the results by actual group by fields as Id is unique to each record. We have more than 2000 records created in a day in some specific cases hence date filter will not help as mentioned in description.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the SOQL query you are executing.